# Make [gtalk] and [googletalk] synonyms of [google-talk]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, stack-overflow, tags, synonym-request

The tags [google-talk](/questions/tagged/google-talk),[gtalk](/questions/tagged/gtalk) and [googletalk](/questions/tagged/googletalk) all refer to the [Google Talk Chat Service](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Talk). I think [google-talk](/questions/tagged/google-talk) is the easiest to read and the other tags should be make synonyms of it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All tags have been merged into [google-talk](/questions/tagged/google-talk), and I added [gtalk](/questions/tagged/gtalk) as a synonym.